# Firebase orderByValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small database which you enter a sports players name and then click icons next to their name to vote them up or down. I'm trying to have the page detect a vote has occured (which seemes to be working) and then reorder the column in accordance to most votes to least votes.

My Firebase looks as so:

```
players
    id (lots of letters/generated by firebase?)
    playerContent: "firstname lastname"
    votes: 1

    id
    playerContent: "differentfirstname differentlastname"
    votes: 2

    id
    playerContent: "thirdname thirdlast"
    votes: 3
```

Here's how I initially reference my database:

```
this.database = this.app.database().ref().child('players');
```

And here's the bulk of the code I've been working with:

```
1.)
    this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
    previousPlayers.push({
    id: snap.key,
    playerContent: snap.val().playerContent,
    votes: snap.val().votes,
  })

2.)
    this.database.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
    var changedVote = snapshot.val();
    console.log("new value: " + changedVote.votes)
    });

3.)
    var votesRef = firebase.database().ref("votes");
    votesRef.orderByValue().on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log("The " + data.key + " votes are " + data.val());
  });
});  

    this.setState({
      players: previousPlayers
      })
     })
    }
```

In #2 there, I am getting immediate feedback in the browser inspect window saying that the up or downvote is registering for each player -- however I think something is wrong in #3. It doesnt seem to change the order of what I see on the screen, even if I refresh the page. It always displays the content in order of oldest at the top, newest on the bottom.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would do the filtering in javascript before rendering your players so the players are always in the right order. I think you're setting the state not correctly and I'm also not sure why you need the `snapshot.forEach`. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0mn1d2ex/). Is it like you need it?

Comment: Thanks for that, there's a lot of useful things there! I'm a little confused with an error I'm getting from   `const orderedPlayers = _.orderBy(players, ['votes'], ['desc']);
   return (`      It's telling me it fails to compile    `Line 84:  '_' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: I'm using lodash dependency and you probably haven't loaded it in your project. If you don't like the that. You could add a sort algorithm with a javascript loop to get your votes 
sorted. But I would use Lodash and just import the `orderBy` method.

Comment: How is your key being set to firebase? I was trying to implement some of your ideas into my existing project and the player.key and playerToVote.key are a few of the things raising concerns. I'm having trouble distinguishing my playerId and key placements here -- https://pastebin.com/9TGR3dxm

Comment: You need to push to firebase with-out data and firebase will create an id for you. Add your data with the returned key.  Please have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data).

Comment: Thanks! I'm catching up a little — I got the lodash working. In Firebase I have an extra attribute for each "player" for their gender. How could I use orderBy or a different lodash to order the players still by votes just like you did, but also have it only include male, or female. That way I could show the best from each gender. I am setting gender by using 1 for female, 0 for male.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158446/discussion-between-idlehand-and-awolf).